# Como evitar scroll en una pagina si ya se está en esa posición?

Tags: jquery

soy relativamente nuevo en esto de html, css, php, javascript y jquery y he estado trabajando en algo pero estoy estancado. en cierta pagina (propia) hay una parte a la que deseo moverme si se hace click, pero cuando ya estoy allí y le doy click de nuevo, se mueve nuevamente desde la parte superior hasta esa parte en específico. les muestro el codigo.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.verde, .blanco, .red').click(function(){
            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 500 }, 800 );
            return false;
        });
    });
```

tengo unas clases que son unas pestañas que se llaman ¨verde, blanco y red¨, cuando hago click en alguna la pantalla hace scroll hasta ellas, pero cuando estoy allí y doy click otra vez, viene desde arriba y se posiciona otra vez hasta donde están esas clases. hay alguna forma de hacer que si uno ya está en esa posición ya no baje otra vez?

De antemano. gracias

Agrego mas codigo a peticion:

```
<div class="tabbed">
                    <!-- Empieza 1er contenedor Higiene Personal -->
                    <div class="tab-content" style="display:block;">
                        <div class="items">
                            <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="image">
                                        <a href="#"><img src="imagenes/higiene1.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                                    </div>
                                    <p>
                                        Producto: <span>Shampoo Head & Shoulders</span><br />
                                        Contenido:<span>1 Litro</span><br />
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="titulo"> <strong></strong></p>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="image">
                                        <a href="#"><img src="imagenes/higiene2.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                                    </div>
                                    <p>
                                        Producto: <span>Desodorante Lady Speed Stick</span><br />
                                        Contenido: <span></span><br />
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="titulo"><strong></strong></p>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="image">
                                        <a href="#"><img src="imagenes/higiene3.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                                    </div>
                                    <p>
                                        Producto: <span>Jabon Dove</span><br />
                                        Contenido:<span>135 Gramos</span><br/><br>
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="titulo"> <strong></strong></p>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="image">
                                        <a href="#"><img src="imagenes/higiene4.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                                    </div>
                                    <p>
                                        Producto: <span>Desodorante Aerosol</span><br />
                                        Contenido : <span><br /><br>

                                    </p>
                                    <p class="titulo"> <strong></strong></p>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="image">
                                        <a href="#"><img src="imagenes/higiene5.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                                    </div>
                                    <p>
                                        Producto: <span> Toallas Femeninas</span><br />
                                        Contenido : <span></span><br/>
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="titulo"> <strong></strong></p>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="image">
                                        <a href="#"><img src="imagenes/higiene6.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                                    </div>
                                    <p>
                                        Producto: <span>Shampoo Loreal Kids</span><br />
                                        Contenido : <span></span><br />
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="titulo"> <strong></strong></p>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="image">
                                        <a href="#"><img src="imagenes/higiene7.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                                    </div>
                                    <p>
                                        Producto: <span>Shampoo Savile</span><br />
                                        Contenido : <span></span><br />

                                    </p>
                                    <p class="titulo"> <strong></strong></p>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="image">
                                        <a href="#"><img src="imagenes/higiene8.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                                    </div>
                                    <p>
                                        Producto: <span>Shampoo Tresemme</span><br />
                                        Contenido : <span></span><br />

                                    </p>
                                    <p class="titulo"> <strong></strong></p>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Termina 1er contenedor -->

                    <!-- Empieza 2do contenedor Limpieza-->
                    <div class="tab-content" style="display:block;">
                        <div class="items">
                            <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="image">
                                        <a href="#"><img src="imagenes/limpieza1.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                                    </div>
                                    <p>
                                        Producto: <span>Detergente en polvo</span><br />
                                        Contenido:<span>900G, 500G</span><br />
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="titulo"> <strong></strong></p>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="image">
                                        <a href="#"><img src="imagenes/limpieza2.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                                    </div>
                                    <p>
                                        Producto: <span>Jab&oacute;n L&iacute;quido para Manos</span><br />
                                        Contenido: <span> 440 ML, 1 Gal&oacute;n</span><br />
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="titulo"> <strong></strong></p>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="image">
                                        <a href="#"><img src="imagenes/limpieza3.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                                    </div>
                                    <p>
                                        Producto: <span>Jab&oacute;n para lavar trastos</span><br />
                                        Contenido:<span>525 ML, 750 ML</span><br/><br>
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="titulo"> <strong></strong></p>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="image">
                                        <a href="#"><img src="imagenes/limpieza4.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                                    </div>
                                    <p>
                                        Producto: <span>Detergente para lavar ropa</span><br/>
                                        Contenido : <span> 10 Litros, 8.3 Litros </span><br/><br>

                                    </p>
                                    <p class="titulo"> <strong></strong></p>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="image">
                                        <a href="#"><img src="imagenes/limpieza5.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                                    </div>
                                    <p>
                                        Producto: <span> Papel Higi&eacute;nico</span><br />
                                        Contenido : <span>40 Rollos doble hoja</span><br/>
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="titulo"> <strong></strong></p>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="image">
                                        <a href="#"><img src="imagenes/limpieza6.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                                    </div>
                                    <p>
                                        Producto: <span>Suavizante de Ropa</span><br />
                                        Contenido : <span>850 ML, 8.5 Litros</span><br />
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="titulo"> <strong></strong></p>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="image">
                                        <a href="#"><img src="imagenes/limpieza7.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                                    </div>
                                    <p>
                                        Producto: <span>Toallas desmaquillantes</span><br />
                                        Contenido : <span></span><br />

                                    </p>
                                    <p class="titulo"> <strong></strong></p>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="image">
                                        <a href="#"><img src="imagenes/limpieza8.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                                    </div>
                                    <p>
                                        Producto: <span>Toallas h&uacute;medas</span><br />
                                        Contenido : <span></span><br />

                                    </p>
                                    <p class="titulo"> <strong></strong></p>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola chapin, deberias de agregar tu HTML.

Comment: Tu código me funciona bien. Parece que tenés algo mal en otro lado.
[Enlace al Codepen](https://codepen.io/Diego23/pen/KxzYER)